# Visual studio 2010 crashes when switching to designer view

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Every time I switch from the code view into designer view Visual studio 2010 crashes and restarts by itself.But before it crashes it displays this error:
     "Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Windows.
     Controls, Version=2.0.5.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35."

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-US/d43e3622-a46a-4302-b13a-726ea5874eb7/vs2010-wp7-designer-instability)'s a solution.

There says, when you remove the reference which cannot be resolved `(in your case System.Windows.Controls)`, it doesn't crash again. After you delete it you can add the reference again, I think.

To delete the reference, open `solution explorer` which usually at the right at the VS, find references folder, right click and then remove it.

[image: here's a picture which shows the references]

Hope it works for you.